# importing .txt file content to datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I found a code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582570/how-to-read-load-text-txt-file-values-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp), to import my data from a text file, to a DataGridView.

```
public void LoadIntoGrid(string path)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            if (lines.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var columnName in lines.FirstOrDefault()
                    .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(columnName, columnName);
                }
                foreach (var cellValues in lines.Skip(1))
                {
                    var cellArray = cellValues
                        .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    if (cellArray.Length == dataGridView1.Columns.Count)
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellArray);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have never used something like this before, and I am lost. I mean - I don't know what is wrong here. The point is that I'm not getting all the columns filled. Just the one that got something like a "break line" after. I will show you in a screen:
[image]

So, as you can see, 152659, 152680, 152684 got a "break line" (not exactly, because there is a "z" in this line) after and only these values get into the datagrid.

Content of the textfile I am using:

> ```
>                                  WYNIKI – PO POPRAWACH (Zarządzanie cz.I)  Gr10 IwB I rok 
>    NR     PR-ZESP    SYSTEM OP.     MT     ZDLN P   ALOK.    Seria,R  ∑ PUN    prznt      T    PROPOZ 
>   ALB.                                                                KTÓW                     OC 
>             02.10       09.10.     16.10    23.10    30.10.   06.11            13.11   06.11 
>  152628      10          7,2         10      9,8        7        9      53       z        3    4 
>  152631      10           6          10      9,3       8,2      7,5     51       z       2+        3 
>  152632      10           7          10      7,5       4,1      6      44,6      z      2/2/z  3 
>  152633      10          6,5         10      7,5       4,1       6     44,1      z        3        3+ 
>  152634      10          4,7         10      8,8       7         6     46,5      z        3        4 
>  148999       0           0          0       9,8        7      7,5     24,3      z      3-/2/z 3 
>  152636      10           6          10      7,2        7        7     47,2      z        3+   4+ 
>  152637      10          7,2         10      9,3       8,2      7,5    52,2      z        3        4 
>  152639      10          4,5         10       0        8,2      9      41,7      z      2/3    3+ 
>  152640      10          6,3         10      5,5        0       8,3    40,1      z       3-        3 
>  152642       0           7          10      9,8        0       5      31,8      z      2 /3   3 
>  152643      10          7,2         10      5,1       7        7,5    46,8      z      2+     3 
>  152644      10          6,3         10      8,8       8,2       5     48,3      z       3+    4+ 
>  152650      10          6,2         10       9         9      9,5     53,7      z        3+       4+ 
>  152651       0          7,5         10      8,8        0        6     32,3      z      3-/z   3 
>  152652      10          4,7         10       7        7         6     44,7      z        3+       4 
>  152654      10          6,3         0       9,8       8,2       5     39,3      z        3-   3 
>  152655       0           0          0        0         0        0        0               0 
>  152659      10          6,5         10      7,5      4,1      8,3     46,4               3        4 
>                                                                                  z                   
>  152660      10          6,2         0        0         0      9,5     25,7      z       3-    P/2 
>  152661      10           7          10       7         0       8,3    42,3      z      2+         3 
>  152665      10          4,7         10      7,5       4,1       6     42,3      z       3+        4 
>  152669      10          7,5         10      9,3       8,2      9       54       z     2+/3       3/4 
>  154874      10          4,5         10      9,3        0       9      42,8      z        2    p/2 
>  152673      10          4,7         10       7         7       6      44,7      z        3        3+ 
>  152675      10           6          10      5,1      8,2        5     44,3      z      2+     3 
>  152676      10          4,5         10      5,1        7      8,3     44,9      z      2+     3 
>  152677      10          6,5         10      5,5        7        6      45       z       3+        4 
>  152678      10          6,3         0       5,5       8,2      9,5    39,5      z        3-       3 
>  152679      10           6          0        0         0        0      16                0 
>  152680      10          7,2         10      5,1        7        9     48,3             2+         3 
>                                                                                  z                   
>  149045      10          6,2         10       9        9        9,5    53,7      z        3        4 
>  152681      10           0          0        0         0        0      10                0 
>  152684      10          6,5         10      5,5        0       0       32               0/3       3 
>                                                                                  z                   
>  152686      10          7,5         10       9         9      9,5      55       z       2+        3 
>  152687      10           7          0        0         0        0      17               0
> ```

What could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

your data by coding is different by txt file . Some of lines of txt file is not full. so it can not show all Infos on the gridview. Check it out your txt file

Comment: Umm... I don't get it, could you explain it in detail?

Comment: the source data has no rules. So the code can't split success by splitting " " .

Comment: but you can new one file with .txt extension .And then typing some data in it . use comma splitting the data in which can be splitted by C#

Comment: Oh okay, but the problem is I can't interfere in the file, because it's being made automatically (and can't change the system actually). That's why I need to separate the collumns by the spacers. Is it even possible to make it work like this?