# C# Read .txt file and insert into dataGrid

Tags: c#, datagridview

**Hello dear stackoverflow.com community,**

I have the following problem, i need to read a .txt file and insert all lines from the File into rows in the Datagrid, i have come to the point to insert all lines from a text file into the datagrid but now i need to get the Value of all Rows and calculate the Hash for each of these and insert them in the same row in a different column, how is that possible can you help me? I have functions to calculate the hash and these Work just i cant get the Value of the current String from the file and calculate the hash! The Lines in the File are seperated by new Lines

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read /load text (\*.txt) file values in datagridview using C# ..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582570/how-to-read-load-text-txt-file-values-in-datagridview-using-c-sharp)